# Regex for find last incidence that is NOT the end character

Tags: regex

I have two URLs from which I need to extract (actually split before) the pagename, i.e. last text string after the last /. For example:

```
https://example.com/en/pagename
https://example.com/en/pagename/
```

My current regex can find the last incidence of the "/" character, but when the / is at the end, I need to select the PREVIOUS / in order to break before the pagename.  Current regex is:

```
\/(?!.*\/)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1

I'd guess,

```
[^/]+/?$
```

or if you wish to capture the `pagename`,

```
([^/]+)/?$
```

might be OK to look into.

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/YsbTux/1/)

---

#### Method 2

For selecting the forward slash right before the end of the URL, we'd try positive lookahead:

```
/(?=[^/]+/?$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/BjkUFM/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YsbTux/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/YsbTux/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: They both seem to capture the page name. What if I want to just zero in on that last slash (but not at end)? I am asking my analytics program to find that slash and split off the rest of the URL into a new field, so I just need that one char selected (the /). 

Sorry if not clear, I guess I need to select the "/" before pagename in both cases.
Thanks!

Comment: That works, but I don't need a zero width. I just need to actually select the "/" with the regex. As long as it's not at the end. Thanks again!

Comment: @dgsinclair In that case you can just take the first slash out of the lookbehind block `/(?=[^/]+(?:/)?$)`

Comment: Thank you both, that does it! /(?=[^/]+(?:/)?$)